# Deploying Github-Passport-Stategy Integrated App with Now

Tags: node.js, express, github, passport.js

I'm new to application deployment, I have an Express application which uses Github's Passport strategy to authenticate users and saves them to a (remote) MongoDB database, when using localhost, my application works as expected.

I'm using the Zeit Now (OSS plan) CLI tool which was installed globally with NPM.

**The issue** 
When I deploy my application using "now" inside the root of the project-folder and then goto "https://github.com/settings/applications/app" and swap the Homepage-URL and the "auth/github/callback" [callback] URL from "http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback" with the URL generated by Now - so it becomes "https://app-name-pxwlglhegg.now.sh/auth/github/callback" I get redirect-uri-mismatch :

```
https://app-name-pxwlglhegg.now.sh/auth/github/callback?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fapps%2Fmanaging-oauth-apps%2Ftroubleshooting-authorization-request-errors%2F%23redirect-uri-mismatch
```

I've tried several times and can't figure it out.

Comment: What is the Authorized redirect URI that you have in your Google developer console? Is the localhost:3000 the one? Is localhost:3000 the only local server you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

You change the callback on GitHub, but the same setting inside your app is not changed. So they mismatch.